# Не проигрывает музыку на андроид

Tags: javascript, mediaplayer

У меня на [сайте](http://onmuz.ru) не воспроизводит песни на мобильных.
В чем может быть проблема? Для андроида может нужно поставить другой плеер? Если да, то какой?

Comment: похоже, ваш метод воспроизведения не поддерживается Android. <audio> работает. Можете например на базе него сделать новый плеер, и использовать его на мобильных

Answer (score 2):

Пора перестать использовать Flash или удивляться, почему он не работает на мобильных устройствах. Используйте [нативные средства HTML5 для воспроизведения аудио.](https://webref.ru/html/audio)

Comment: но плеер на js . flash a нету...

Comment: Ага, а по адресу http://onmuz.ru/style/new_player/player.swf .swf файл для красоты лежит. И в DOM'е он просто так отрисовывается.

Comment: Напишите мне в скайп: blits00, придумаем кроссплатформенное решение.

Comment: Андрей, я отправил запрос прими... либо напиши на скайп levonx96  или http://vk.com/levonx